# How do I optimize this ruby method? It parses a query result in to an array.

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's what I have:

```
def existing_photos
  @existing_photos = Array.new
  event.photos.each do |ep|
    @existing_photos << URI.unescape(ep.dropbox_path.split('/').last) rescue []
  end
  @existing_photos
end
```

It returns an array of filenames from a database query. I'm sure there's a more ruby-like way to do this.

I also have a similiar method that does the same thing with a dropbox-api `ls` result.

```
def all_photos
  @all_photos = Array.new
  @dropbox_files.each do |dbf|
    @all_photos << dbf.path.split('/').last
  end
  @all_photos
end
```

that i think should be optimized as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't an optimization problem, it's a style and idiom question probably more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do this...

```
def existing_photos
  event.photos.map { |ep|
    URI.unescape(ep.dropbox_path.sub(%r{.*/}, '') rescue nil
  }.compact
end
```

Take `event.photos` which is array like and map it using the block to convert it to what you want.  Compact it at the end to handle the nil cases.  The use of `sub` is just a preference and may be faster than splitting the path and picking the last element (but you might want to time it to see).

Comment: +1 but I'd probably keep the `split('/').last` as the intent is very clear. Unless the slight difference in performance was critical for some reason. Also, because I'm a stickler about naming and its affect on readability, I'd rename `ep` to `photo`.

Comment: Similarly for `all_photos`: `@dropbox_files.map{|file| file.path.split('/').last}`. Isn't this really `all_files`?

Comment: @MarkThomas Good point.  I suppose one might also consider File.basename(ep.dropbox_path) as well...

Comment: That's even better. Technically better OS support (but what OS doesn't accept `/` as a directory separator anymore) :)

Comment: @MarkThomas Yes, for the `@dropbox_files` it's just all of the files in a dir on dropbox

Comment: @afxjzs Then I would call the method `all_files`.